# Get item from entity framework by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

Simple question. I have entity Customer in my edmx model. I need to get the customer with Id = 20 in c#. How do I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Entities.Customer.First(c => c.CustomerId == 20);
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something. here's what I got:  Project1.OrderEntities oe = new Project1.OrderEntities();
oe.Customers.First(c => c.CustomerId == 20); There's no property "First" in there.

Comment: `First` is a Linq extension method.  Put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file.

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to use .First() or .FirstOrDefault(). The difference comes down to whether you want a null or an exception in the case that your customer does not exist.

The .First() method will throw an exception if there are no matching results in the database. The .FirstOrDefault() method will return null if there are no matching results in the database

```
Customer customer21 = oe.Customers.First(c => c.CustomerId == 20); // throws an exception if customer 21 does not exist

Customer customer21 = oe.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == 20); // null if customer 21 does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) approach, as follows:

```
Customer customerRecord = 
    (from customer in Entities.Customers
     where customer.id == 20
     select customer).FirstOrDefault();
```

Using `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if the element with that ID doesn't exist, as opposed to `First()` which will throw an exception. Also, make sure to include, `using System.Linq;` before using LINQ statements.

Hope this helps.